# How to compile openzwave-control-panel?

Tags: 10.04, compiling

Trying to compile [openzwave-control-panel](http://code.google.com/p/openzwave-control-panel/source/browse/).
But getting the following error:

```
user@ubuntu1004desktop:~/openzwave-control-panel$ make
g++ -o ozwcp -g ozwcp.o webserver.o zwavelib.o   ../libmicrohttpd/src/daemon/.libs/libmicrohttpd.a -pthread -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation
g++: ../libmicrohttpd/src/daemon/.libs/libmicrohttpd.a: No such file or directory
g++: IOKit: No such file or directory
g++: CoreFoundation: No such file or directory
make: *** [ozwcp] Error 1
```

(yes, I have [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/s/libmicrohttpd/), but there is no *.libs* folder)

Also, I can not configure the sources:

```
user@ubuntu1004desktop:~/libmicrohttpd$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

How to compile that?

Comment: you cold side step the problem with building ozwcp by using the zwaver chrome extension
instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the libmicrohttpd folder you need to run `autoreconf -fi`

You'll need to have `autoconf`, `libtool` and `texinfo` installed as well before running `autoreconf -fi`.

This should generate a correct `configure` file

However "IOKit" and "CoreFoundation" are specific MacOS libraries.  My suggestion is to look at the Makefile - you will probably find that you have to comment out specific MacOS lines and uncomment out lines to allow you to compile for Linux.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I had to find another version of libmicrohttpd, since the original version didn't contain files needed (probably, usage of libtool and texinfo would help to generate them).

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the Makefile that says uncomment out the next five lines if you are using a Mac. If you aren't using a Mac, make sure those five lines are commented out. That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please share with me compiled version (+ openzwave lib)?

Comment: I had the same after following that gist: https://gist.github.com/chriskacerguis/681a1a6782abd57b69759d61c0571288